# Show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $v_1 = (1,-1,2,-2)$ and $v_2 = (0,0,-1,1)$.
>
> Let $v_3 = (1,0,0,0)$ and $v_4 =(1,1,1,1)$.
>
> Show that $\mathcal{B} = \{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4 \}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

---

After showing that $\mathcal{B} $ is set of independent vectors and that $\operatorname{Vect}(v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and its dimension is the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^4$. I don't see how to proceed to get $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @amWhy, your edit erased the definition of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Comment: Could you show what you used to show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a set of independent vectors, etc,

Comment: Four independent vectors that span $\mathbb R^{4}$...What does it mean for vectors to span a vector space?  I think you're info meets the definition.

Comment: @amWhy I have found that $ av_1 + bv_2  + cv_3 + dv_4 = 0 \implies a = b = c = d = 0$. which means the set of vectors are independent.

Comment: @Zourhair Yes, for my first comment.  Independence.  Then it's just a matter of proving that the four vectors **span** $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: @amWhy That is where I have the problem. I don't know how to show those vectors span $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Four independent vectors in $\mathbb R^4$ must span $\mathbb R^4.$ See @gimusi's answer.

Comment: @ZouhairElYaagoubi Ever heard of determinant? An invertible matrix ensures vector can be made in one unique way with your given vectors. Done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\mathcal{B}$ is a set of $4$ linearly independent vectors (i.e. span $\mathbb{R}^4$) it is by definition a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Indeed note that forall $b\in\mathbb{R}^4$ the following system

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\ -2 & 1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}x=b$$

has an unique solution then $\mathcal{B}$ span $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: @amWhy Never mind! Thanks

Comment: There, you're the original and correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

In a four dimensional vector space every set of four linearly independent vectors constitutes a basis for the space.

Since you have proved $$ B=\{ v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$$ are linearly independent vectors,
$B$  is a basis for $\mathbb {R}^4 $

Comment: This is a duplicate of the earlier posted answer (earlier answer posted 12 minutes prior to your post).  No need to duplicate a post already saying what you try to say again.

Answer (score 2):

To show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a set of linearly independent vectors, it's sufficient to show that :

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 & 2 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

cannot be "Gauss-Eliminated" aka it's irreducible. Since Gauss-Elimination is a starter-pack tool in Linear Algebra, you should definitely be familiar with it and by matrix operations (row swaps - subtractions), you should easily conclude it. If one is able to bring this matrix to an echelon form consisting of the $4$ unit vectors of $\mathbb R^4$, it means that not only these vectors are linearly independent (since its dimension won't be reduced) but also that they span $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: It's an alternative way of proving both questions. Why downvote without reason?